# Intercept calls to window.frameElement in cefsharp

Tags: c#, cefsharp

In my WinForms project, I am opening a CefSharp browser and loading an external url that is not in my control. Normally, this URL is opened as a iframe within external application.

The page interacts with its parent window using `window.frameElement` and calls some function on `window.frameElement`.

In CefSharp, I am not able to stub out `window.frameElement`.

Is there anyother way to know when the page has called some function on `window.frameElement`.

Comment: Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28067549/how-to-trap-listen-javascript-function-or-events-in-cefsharp?

Comment: It doesn't work with window.frameElement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is going to be pretty hacky, but I'm sharing regardless. I created a simple example which worked for me, I hope it will help you as well.

The JavaScript side is just a plain HTML with a button which invokes an event handler on click:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Test</title>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="onClick()">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

The event handler just invokes a random function (doesn't even have to exist on `frameElement`) with some arguments:

**app.js**

```
function onClick() {
    var x = window.frameElement.greet("Hello", "world");
}
```

The C# side has a `ChromiumWebBrowser` pointing to the address of my page:

**Form1.Designer.cs**

```
this.browser = new CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser("http://localhost:3000/index.html");
```

I subscribe to the `FrameLoadEnd` event:

```
this.browser.FrameLoadEnd += BrowserOnFrameLoadEnd;
```

The handler injects some JavaScript code into the main/top frame (our main page):

**Form1.cs**

```
private void BrowserOnFrameLoadEnd(object sender, FrameLoadEndEventArgs frameLoadEndEventArgs)
{
    if (frameLoadEndEventArgs.Frame.IsMain)
    {
        frameLoadEndEventArgs.Frame.ExecuteJavaScriptAsync(@"
(function() {
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'frameElement', {
        writable: true
    });

    window.frameElement = {};

    window.frameElement = new Proxy(window.frameElement, {
        get: function (target, propKey, receiver) {
            return function(...args) {
                window.frameElementInterceptor.intercept(propKey, args);
            };
        }
    });
})();");
    }
}
```

The injected code modifies the `window.frameElement` to capture property getters using an [ES6 Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy). This way when the original page does `window.frameElement.someMethod(arg1, arg2)` I can inject my custom logic.

The custom logic I'm injecting is to call the `frameElementInterceptor`'s `intercept` method with the name of the function that was called and the arguments that were passed in.

Going back to the C# side, we register a JS object with the CEFSharp browser and make it available as `frameElementInterceptor` on the global scope in JS:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public class FrameElementInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(string propKey, object[] args)
    {
        MessageBox.Show($@"Function '{propKey}' was called with arguments: [{string.Join(", ", args)}]",
@"Function call intercepted");
    }
}

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // .....

    browser.RegisterJsObject("frameElementInterceptor", new FrameElementInterceptor());
}
```

Now all the pieces are in place and whenever I click the button in the page, my C# interceptor gets the message:

[image: MessageBox from C#]

**Caveat**: although this simple example works, but I'm sure there are all kinds of edge cases not considered here, so I would be very wary with putting this in production. 
Also I think a better solution would involve code change from CefSharp's side. They could enable registering of types that derive from `DynamicObject` and enable overriding existing objects on `window` (like `frameElement`). As far as I know there is no progress on this since [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36489890/dynamicobjects-dont-register-with-registerjsobject-with-chromium-cefsharp).